# If $A$ and $B$ are self-adjoint and positive operators show that also their product $C=AB$ is self-adjoint and positive

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory, self-adjoint-operators

If $A$ and $B$ are self-adjoint and positive operators show that also their product $C=AB$ is self-adjoint and positive.

Can somebody help me with this problem? I would show my work but  I don't have any idea how to do it.

Comment: Given $A^T=A$ and $B^T=B$, AB=(AB)^T$ if and only if $AB=BA$, which is generally false.

Comment: That's why I'm stuck 'cause it doesn't say that $A$ and $B$ commute

Comment: Take two noncommuting positive definite symmetric matrices. This yields a counterexample to the statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Sylvester's criterion, the symmetric matrices
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 2 \end{bmatrix},\qquad
B=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 3 \end{bmatrix}
$$
are positive definite. However,
$$
C=\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 4 \\ 3 & 7 \end{bmatrix}
$$
is not symmetric.