# $A$ and $B$ are positive self-adjoint matrix such that $AB$ is self-adjoint then $AB$ is positive

Tags: linear-algebra, hilbert-spaces, inner-products, adjoint-operators, self-adjoint-operators

Question: $A$ and $B$ are positive self-adjoint matrix such that $AB$ is self-adjoint then prove that $AB$ is positive.

My first try: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3798613/if-a-and-b-are-self-adjoint-and-positive-operators-show-that-also-their-prod) I can see that the same question was there but it has a little amount of typo. What I have to prove is that $(x, ABx)>0$ for all $x>0$.

Now, $(x,ABx)=(Ax,Bx)=(BAx,x)$ now we also have that $AB=BA$ because $AB=(AB)^*=B^*A^*=BA$ because $A,B,AB$ are all self-adjoint and we can also see that $(BAx,Ax)>0$ but I can't get rid of $A$ in the 2nd co-ordinate.

My second try: Then I tried using this result that "if $A$ and $B$ are positive self-adjoint matrix then there exist a basis $x_1,\cdots, x_n$ of $X$ satisfies an eqn of the form $$Ax_j=\lambda_j Bx_j.$$
where $\lambda_j$ is real."
Now $A,B$ are positive $\Rightarrow \lambda_j>0$ using Generalised Raleigh quotient then $$(x_j,ABx_j)=(Ax_j,Bx_j)=(\lambda_j Bx_j,Bx_j)=\lambda_j||Bx_j||^2>0.$$
Hence $AB$ is positive.
Here I am confused that what is the place where I used $AB$ is self-adjoint! Please help. You can also help me with different proofs.

Comment: Please make clear what is the framework, and what you want to show. (What is given in the first sentence, and what is the conclusion. Just use some separating comma. Best a point.) Then why do we have $AB=BA$? Please make clear which is the question.

Comment: I hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, it helps, thanks! And we also have the place where we need $AB$ self-adjoint. This was the (only) question?

Comment: Yes in my approach in the second try. Can you see the place where I used $AB$ is self adjoint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us start with the positive operators $A$, $B$ as in the OP. Then $AB$ self-adjoint implies
$$
AB = (AB)^*=B^*A^*=BA\ ,
$$
so that $AB$ are commuting. Using continuous functional calculus w.r.t. the function $f(x)=\sqrt x$ defined on $[0,\infty)$ (and this domain contains the spectrum of $A$, and the spectrum of $B$) we obtain square roots $S=f(A)$, $T=f(B)$, i.e. $A=S^2$, and $T=B^2$.

Explicitly, for $A$ only, let $p_n$ be a sequence of polynomials such that $p_n\to f$ on a compact interval (for instance $[0,\|A\|]$) contaning the spectrum of $A$. Such a sequence is insured by [Stone-Weierstraß](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem). Then $$p_n(A)\to f(A)=:S\ .$$
Here, $f(A)$ is defined as $\lim p_n(A)$, the limit exists, Cauchy sequence. (Functional calculus of bounded operators shows this does not depend on $(p_n)$, but we do not need this.)
We denote by $S$ this value.

Then
$$
\begin{aligned}
S^2
&=(f(A))^2=(\lim p_n(A))^2=\lim (p_n(A))^2
=\lim p_n^2(A)
\\
&=(\lim p_n^2)(A)
=(\lim p_n)^2(A)
\\
&=f^2(A)=\operatorname{id}(A)=A\ .
\\[3mm]
SB &=(\lim p_n(A))B=\lim p_n(A)B\\
&=\lim B p_n(A)=B(\lim p_n(A))=BS\ .
\\[3mm]
(S^*x, y)
&=(x,Sy)=(x,(\lim p_n(A))y)=(x,\lim p_n(A)y)=\lim (x,p_n(A)y)\\
&=\lim (p_n(A)x,y)=(\lim p_n(A)x,y)=((\lim p_n(A))x,y)\\
&=(Sx,y)\ ,\qquad\text{ for all $x,y$ in the given Hilbert space.}
\end{aligned}
$$
(We have used $AB=BA$. These properties are basic properties of the functional calculus. Starting from $AB=BA$ we get to $f(A)B=Bf(A)$, so $SB=BS$. Similarly, starting with $SB=BS$ we obtain $Sf(B)=f(B)S$. So $ST=TS$ the two operators $S,T$ also commute.)

Let now $x$ be $\ne 0$. We have in a row:
$$
(ABx,x) =(SSTTx,x)=(TSSTx,x)=(STx,STx)=\|STx\|^2>0\ .
$$
(We have $(STx,STx)=\|STx\|^2\ge 0$, and in case of an equality, from $(STx,STx)=0$ we get first $Tx=0$, since $S>0$, then from $(Tx,Tx)=0$ also $x=0$, since $T>0$. Contradiction, since we started with an $x\ne 0$.)

---

Alternatively, we could have intoduced only $T$, and have the same argument with $SS$ replaced by $A$, e.g. $(ABx,x)=(ATTx,x)=(TATx,x)=(ATx,Tx)>0$ since $Tx\ne 0$ since $(Tx,Tx)=(TTx,x)=(Bx,x)>0$.

---

*Note:* In case of finitely dimensional spaces, things are simple. The two commuting self-adjoint operators can be diagonalized simultaneously w.r.t. some ortonormal basis, and if $A=\operatorname{diag}(a_1,\dots,a_n)>0$, then $S=\sqrt A:=
\operatorname{diag}(\sqrt{a_1},\dots,\sqrt{a_n})>0$ is the explicit square root of $A$ (which is positive), it is diagonal w.r.t. the same basis, et caetera.

---

*Note:* See also

- [Functional calculus for bounded operators using continuous functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_functional_calculus)
- [Functional calculus for bounded operators using Borel functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_functional_calculus)

Comment: Can you please expand the continuous functional part? I don't know why $AB=BA$ implies $f(A)B=Bf(A)$ and $Af(B)=f(B)A$ and then $ST=TS$. I can see it, if $f$ is a polynomial but if it is a square root, how do you extend it?

Comment: And Why is $S,T$ self adjoint what I got is $(S^*)^2=S^2$?

Answer (score 1):

We can use a nice trick here given that both $A$ and $B$ are positive. As $A$ is positive, this implies that $A$ has a unique positive square root, $A^{\frac{1}{2}}$, which being positive has an inverse $A^{-\frac{1}{2}}$. Thus,
$$AB = A^{\frac{1}{2}}A^{\frac{1}{2}}BA^{\frac{1}{2}}A^{-\frac{1}{2}}$$
So we can see that $A^{\frac{1}{2}}BA^{\frac{1}{2}}$ is similar to AB. Thus showing $A^{\frac{1}{2}}BA^{\frac{1}{2}}$ is positive implies that $AB$ is positive.

For self-adjoint: $\left(A^{\frac{1}{2}}BA^{\frac{1}{2}}\right)^*=\left(A^{\frac{1}{2}}\right)^*B^*\left(A^{\frac{1}{2}}\right)^* = A^{\frac{1}{2}}BA^{\frac{1}{2}}$ because both $A^{\frac{1}{2}}$ and $B$ are self-adjoint.

For positive: For any $v\in V\setminus \{0\}$ as $A^{\frac{1}{2}}$ is invertible we have that $A^{\frac{1}{2}}v \neq 0$ and thus $\langle A^{\frac{1}{2}}BA^{\frac{1}{2}}v,v\rangle = \langle BA^{\frac{1}{2}}v, A^{\frac{1}{2}}v\rangle>0$ as $A^{\frac{1}{2}}$ is self-adjoint, and $B$ is positive.

Therefore $A^{\frac{1}{2}}BA^{\frac{1}{2}}$ is positive implying that $AB$ is positive as desired. In general when proving results given a positive operator it may be easier to prove the result for a similar operator using the above trick.