# If $A\geq0$ and $B\leq 0$ do we have $AB\leq 0$ and $BA\leq 0$ in terms of operators?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, analysis, operator-theory

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space with inner product $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$. We say $A\geq 0$ if $\langle Ax,x\rangle\geq0$ for all $x\in H$ (and similarly $\leq 0$). If $A\geq0$ and $B\leq 0$ do we have $AB\leq 0$ and $BA\leq 0$?

Comment: Up to replacing $B$ by $-B$, this is the same as asking "Does $A\geq 0$ and $B\geq 0$ imply $AB\geq 0$". This is false ($AB$ might not even be symmetric) and I'm sure this has been asked before on this site ... here for example https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2001516/prove-that-the-product-of-two-positive-linear-operators-is-positive-if-and-only or here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3798613/if-a-and-b-are-self-adjoint-and-positive-operators-show-that-also-their-prod?rq=1

Comment: In fact, $A \geq 0$ does not imply $A^{2} \geq 0$.

Comment: @geetha290krm In the complex inner product space $A\ge 0$ does imply $A^2\ge 0.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc True. I made the comment because OP did not specify the scalar field.

Answer (score 1):

Much like my [other answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4704821) I'd like to add to the comments by saying that lack of self-adjointness can be fixed as follows:

> Given bounded linear operators $A,B$ on $H$ be given. If $B\leq 0\leq A$, then
> $$
> \sqrt AB\sqrt A\leq 0\qquad\text{and}\qquad
> \sqrt{-B}(-A)\sqrt{-B}\leq 0
> $$
> where $\sqrt{(\cdot)}$ is the [unique square root](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4417721).

Using self-adjointness of $\sqrt A,\sqrt{-B}\geq 0$ we compute
$$
\langle x,\sqrt AB\sqrt A\rangle=\langle(\sqrt Ax),B(\sqrt Ax)\rangle\leq 0
$$
for all $x\in H$ (and analogously for $\sqrt{-B}(-A)\sqrt{-B}$).